# Programatically retrieve an attachment stored on a note on a CRM 4.0 entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, attachment, dynamics-crm-4

How would you suggest working with files that is stored on the note of a entity in Crm.  Could you write a generic method that will enable you to access any type of file?  Or would it be better to have a method for dealing with each type of file?

For example, we are going to be saving a mix of swf files and xml files on the entity, so would it make sense to have a method each for example:

- GetXmlFilesOnAccount(accountid)
- GetSwfFilesOnAccount(accountid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion using your methods:

```
* GetXmlFilesOnAccount(accountid)
* GetSwfFilesOnAccount(accountid)
```

1. Retrieve account activitypointers by regardingobjectid(in your case accountid guid)
2. Loop through returned activitypointers
3. Get attachments for each activitypointer (activitypointer.activityid = activitymimeattachment.activityid)
4. Store attachments (disk, etc)

You don't even need two methods. You can retrieve all attachment file types for a given note (annotation) with a single method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

When you upload an attachment to CRM the mimetype is also saved as part of the record information. 
The following link contains a nice example of how to download the attachemt using a single method. http://crmscape.blogspot.com/2009/10/ms-crm-40-sending-attachments-to.html

The post is missing the actual query needed to retrieve the annotations but you can tell what columns are required from the method signature.

Answer (score 1):

I recently started an Open Source Project on CodePlex to accomplish exactly that. Feel free to check out the Project's Web Page at:

http://crmattachdownload.codeplex.com/

You can also view the source code under the "Source Code" tab of that same page.

Pete